# Global session implementation in Spring boot

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I am developing an application which will be used on 10 machines. Operator can log in to this application on 1 machine, but then he can't login to this app on another machine. How can we check if he is logged in on another machine using session? Can we really implement this using session? Or do we need to use database to track the users? Please suggest.

Comment: you can try spring-security

Comment: We are using KeyCloak for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Check [JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a
>   compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information
>   between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and
>   trusted because it is digitally signed.
>
> **When should you use JSON Web Tokens?**
>
> **Authentication**: This is the most common scenario for using JWT. Once the user is logged in, each subsequent request will include the
>   JWT, allowing the user to access routes, services, and resources that
>   are permitted with that token. Single Sign On is a feature that widely
>   uses JWT nowadays, because of its small overhead and its ability to be
>   easily used across different domains.
>
> **Information Exchange**: JSON Web Tokens are a good way of securely transmitting information between parties. Because JWTs can be
>   signed—for example, using public/private key pairs—you can be sure the
>   senders are who they say they are. Additionally, as the signature is
>   calculated using the header and the payload, you can also verify that
>   the content hasn't been tampered with.

So when you successfully log in on 1 machine, you would receive JWT which contains data and signature which can be verified on other machines without hitting a database.

Some examples:

- [Secure a Spring Boot REST API With JSON Web Token + Reference to Angular Integration](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50)
- [REST Security with JWT using Java and Spring Securit](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java)